# Is it possible to get a list of App Engine instances via gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine

The title says it all. Just to irritate DRY purists, I'll say it again.

Is it possible to get a list of instances my application is running on via **gcloud**?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Compute Engine instances are not the same as App Engine Instances. If I get it right, the question is about App Engine instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine can mean traditional App Engine or Managed VMs, depending on the context. There is only one App Engine app per project, but you can have multiple modules (although only one of those module will serve web traffic, the rest are backend only) and multiple versions of each module.

As pgiecek mention,

```
gcloud preview app modules list
```

will show all the modules.

What you might be looking for is all your App Engine versions, for which you will still have to use appcfg

```
appcfg.py -A <your-project-id> [-M <module>] list_versions
```

If you are using Managed VMs, it will spin up your app on GCE instances, in which case

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

does in fact show your App Engine (MVM) instances.

Answer (score 4):

In 2019, You can check the newest document : [gcloud app services list - list your existing services](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/services/list)

The newest command is:

```
gcloud app services list
```

The result will be something like this.

```
SERVICE  NUM_VERSIONS
default  7
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that currently it is not possible. At the moment gcloud tool supports App Engine (via Preview CLI command groups) but provides only limited number of operations and furthermore they are in BETA. You can check documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/).

You can only list your existing deployed modules and versions as follows.

```
gcloud preview app modules list
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Sep 2019 (Google Cloud SDK 237.0.0):

`gcloud app instances list`

[image]